# Ошибка подключения API VK на локальном хосте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема при подключении к API VK

```
Ошибка такая: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.vk.com/method/friends.search?user_id=МОЙ ID&access_token=ТУТ КЛЮЧ): failed to open stream: ��������� �� �����������, �.�. ������ ������� ������ ������ �� ���������. in D:\xampp\htdocs\vkpanel\index.php on line 6
```

Расшифровать не получается

Поддержка VK помочь не смогла, порекомендовала сменить программу на XAMPP.
Установил её но все та же ошибка. До этого пользовался Open Server, где тоже была ошибка.

Если использовать запрос через URL браузера или установить данный скрипт на хостинг все в порядке, то есть по сути проблемы связана на самом ПК.
Брандмауэр и антивирус отключал, это не помогает.

***Кто может подсказать, в чем заключается проблема. Очень долго уже пытаюсь решить её***

Comment: А `file_get_contents` на других урлах нормально работает? В том числе https? Например эту страницу удастся получить?

Comment: Суть в том, что при обращение к API VK через компьютер, вообще не работает либо ошибки или черзе CURL без ошибки но и при этом ни чего не происходит. Работает только: 1) запросом через URL: api.vk.com/method/friends.search?user_id=МОЙ ID&access_token=Тут ключ 2) установка скрипта на хостин

Comment: К сожалению "вообще не работает" мне ни о чем не говорит. У вас конкретное сообщение об ошибке "failed to open stream" - возможно проблема с настройкой file_get_contents, поэтому я и спрашивал про другие урлы и вопрос так и остался. А CURL - " ни чего не происходит" - это возвращает пустую строку?

Comment: Если получать URL данной страницы, пишет failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request . CURL возвращает пустой запрос, скорее всего не может подключится .